Uploading video to S3 via sidekiq / Carrierwave on Heroku rails app
I have a Rails 7 app running on Heroku. The app is simple, in theory: Users sign up, and can upload video files as part of a survey.
I'm using Carrierwave for the upload process, but ran into memory and timeout issues using Heroku. I've tried to implement the carrierwave-backgrounder gem alongside sidekiq and redis.
I've pushed to a staging app on Heroku and the timeouts on form submit seem to be resolved, but the files aren't being uploaded to the S3 bucket. I've set the S3 credentials in the staging app's config vars the same as on the production app.
Inspecting the Video record in the rails console shows filenames in the relevant table columns, but no files are showing in the S3 bucket.
Video.rb:
class Video < ApplicationRecord

  mount_uploaders :video_files, VideoUploader
  store_in_background :video_files

end


carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        # required
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),                        # required unless using use_iam_profile
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),                        # required unless using use_iam_profile
    use_iam_profile:       true,                         # optional, defaults to false
    region:                ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION')                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV.fetch('S3_BUCKET_NAME')                                    # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                                 # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = { cache_control: "public, max-age=#{365.days.to_i}" } # optional, defaults to {}
  # For an application which utilizes multiple servers but does not need caches persisted across requests,
  # uncomment the line :file instead of the default :storage.  Otherwise, it will use AWS as the temp cache store.
  # config.cache_storage = :file
end

VideoUploader.rb
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
  cache_storage CarrierWave::Storage::File

  def cache_dir
    "uploads_cache/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_allowlist
    %w(mp4 mov avi)
  end
end

initializers/carrierwave_backgrounder.rb
CarrierWave::Backgrounder.configure do |c|
  c.backend :sidekiq, queue: :carrierwave
end

initializers/sidekiq.rb
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = {
    url: ENV["REDIS_URL"],
    ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }
  }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = {
      url: ENV["REDIS_URL"],
      ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE }
  }
end

sidekiq.yml
:queues:
  - [carrierwave, 1]
  - default

redis.rb
$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV["REDIS_URL"], ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })

Procfile
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 2


@dbugger The video files I'm testing with are under 10MB

If you read the docs for carrierWave_backgrounder, store_in_background is not recommended for heroku, it suggests to use process_in_background

You're completely right, @dbugger, I don't know how I missed that. Now I can upload multiple files fine, but files uploaded previously to the previous table column no longer show on the site. VideoUploader previously used the video_file column on Videos, which was a string. When I realised that I needes multiple file uploads in the form, I made the form upload to video_files instead, which is an array type. I don't know why files in video_file are no longer loading.

that is another question

You're right, I'll make a different post. Thank you for your help.
